# Browsersync stopped working after update

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, browser-sync

Everything worked fine before and updated my mac to the latest version 10.12.2 and it just stopped.

I'm using Gulp with Browsersync and when starting Gulp it says that address in use already, but nothing is running else. Tried killing all processes with port :8000, but doesn't help.

```
iMaxs-MacBook-Pro-2:_Cveti Max$ gulp
[08:56:31] Using gulpfile ~/_GIM/_Cveti/gulpfile.js
[08:56:31] Starting 'browser_sync'...
[08:56:31] Finished 'browser_sync' after 7.16 ms
[08:56:31] Starting 'watch'...
[08:56:31] Finished 'watch' after 18 ms
[08:56:31] Starting 'default'...
[08:56:31] Finished 'default' after 20 μs
[Fri Dec 16 08:56:31 2016] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: Address already in use)
[Fri Dec 16 08:56:31 2016] 127.0.0.1:50700 [404]: / - No such file or directory
[Fri Dec 16 08:56:31 2016] 127.0.0.1:50703 [404]: / - No such file or directory
[BS] Proxying: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[BS] Access URLs:
 ----------------------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000/app/mob/ru.php
    External: http://10.10.66.223:3000/app/mob/ru.php
 ----------------------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://10.10.66.223:3001
 ----------------------------------------------------
/Users/Max/_GIM/_Cveti/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/public/init.js:25
            return args.cb(new Error("Instance: " + name + " is already running!"));
                        ^

TypeError: args.cb is not a function
    at Object.init (/Users/Max/_GIM/_Cveti/node_modules/browser-sync/lib/public/init.js:25:25)
    at /Users/Max/_GIM/_Cveti/gulpfile.js:203:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Max/_GIM/_Cveti/node_modules/gulp-connect-php/index.js:131:5)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/Max/_GIM/_Cveti/node_modules/gulp-connect-php/index.js:23:13)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:474:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:363:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:548:20)
```